# Logout and Login

Tags: feature-request, login, logout

Well, I finally reclaimed my identity.  It took me hours -- the "logout" was hard to find, so I was trapped in a new identities on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.

Then I had to locate "login" -- It was also hard to find. And clicked through the button that is labeled wrong 'create new account' in order to get to the place where I could use my email -- instead of only having the OpenID option.

(The Logout and Login are in the pulldown labeled "StackExchange" -- A place I never go.)

Please consider some of the difficulties I had with the UI.

So the questions/requests:

- Can you relabel that button to make it obvious that you need to use it even if you have an existing account.
- Make logout more obvious.

Comment: Congrats, You've fallen for the SE trick. Once you are in, we don't want you to log out.

Comment: @Bhargav are you saying that SE is *Hotel California*? :-P

Comment: @JonClements, sssh, Don't disclose that in public.

Comment: Just a FYI, SO is working on building out a new site navigation.  I think they changed this in the new navigation.

Comment: There should be a badge for logging out.

Comment: @DavidG - Hmmm.. Interesting idea; what is the "benefit" to the user and/or system of logging out?

Comment: @RickJames Well, I was only kidding about getting a badge, I don't think it's such a good idea to encourage people to be logged out :)

Comment: @DavidG - But a lot of upvoters think it is a good idea??

Comment: @RickJames I think a lot of upvoters thought it was a funny joke! But maybe...

Comment: @NathanOliver it's not that different. It's still hidden away in the StackExchange  menu

Comment: @wpercy Apart from accidentally introducing a CSS bug, they haven't changed the network pop-down one bit.

Comment: I'd really support the introduction of a logout button. Logging out can be very important, e.g. when you are on a shared machine. In the new layout it's even harder to find and more unintuitiv. That's bad exspecially for new users.

Comment: Seriously though, where is the logout link?

Comment: @iyrin Click the Hamburger/speech bubble in the upper right corner.

Comment: @iyrin then click *log out*.

Comment: Finding the log out link should be a silver badge.

Comment: Seriously.. this is a dark pattern. Why is this issue not addressed for over a year? Shared machines is one reason, but just now I wanted to logout + login to test the new (non-OpenID) Login I just created. Note that creating a new Login does not ask a password confirmation, so I needed to re-login to ensure I typed correctly. Sure, you want users to stay logged in, but hiding the logout this way is just bad, IMHO.

Comment: FYI the logout option is in the pulldown labeled "A list of all 174 StackExchange sites" (the right-most icon that looks like a text balloon).. it is no longer labeled just 'StackExchange' as mentioned above.